# Turn off logging EFCore logging for nunit tests

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, nunit

I have unit tests for a project with EF core 7.0.
I use the InMemory provider to test queries to the database.
Each test generates a lot of messages like this:

```
Context 'MyContext' started tracking 'Player' entity. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see key values.
```

If I turn this option on, I see the following message:

```
Context 'MyContext' started tracking 'Player' entity with key '{Id: 1}'.
```

Is there a way to turn such messages off completely?

**UPDATE**

I tried to use `NullLoggerProvider`, so my method for database creation looks as follows:

```cs
var loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory();
loggerFactory.AddProvider(NullLoggerProvider.Instance);
return new(new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>()
    .UseLoggerFactory(loggerFactory)
    .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName)
    .Options);
```

I've also added `appsettings.json` to the Test project, which looks:

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "None"
    }
  }
}
```

but it didn't help.

Comment: Are those log messages outputted through the ILogger? If so, can't you just configure the NullLogger as part of your tests?

Comment: I tried to use code 
```var loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory(); loggerFactory.AddProvider(new NullLoggerProvider());
```
But I've got `cannot access to internal constructor of NullLoggerProvider` error.
I suppose it worked for previous versions of EF, but it doesn't for EF Core 7

Comment: Try `loggerFactory.AddProvider(NullLoggerProvider.Instance);`

Comment: It didn't help. I still can see all the logs :(

Comment: I'm wondering what will happen if you in your test project add an `appsettings.json` file and set the default log level to `None`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#configure-logging

Comment: No luck :( I've updated the post according to your questions.

Comment: I'm running out of suggestions. The only thing I can think of is if EF outputs messages through Console.WriteLine and not through the logging framework.

Answer (score 1):

After trying the solutions above, wading through the EFCore configuration documentation and experiencing similar behavior with xUnit testing (to the point of my pipelines failing because the logging was too excessive), I found the following info from Microsoft:

[EF Core testing without the database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/testing-without-the-database#in-memory-provider)

> using the in-memory provider for testing is strongly discouraged; consider using SQLite instead, or implementing the repository pattern.

[EF Core testing using SQLite in-memory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/testing-without-the-database#sqlite-in-memory)

[EF Core testing using repository pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/testing-without-the-database#repository-pattern)

*Additionally, as stated in this link*

[EF Core In-Memory Database Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/in-memory/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)

> Important - New features are not being added to the in-memory database.

Time for a different approach!